# Pivot point doesn't move in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

I have an issue where if I move entire objects in edit mode then the pivot point won't move with them. it does move in object mode though. I checked if "Affects only origin" was turned on but it isn't. Can anyone please help? Im new to the software.

PS: I'm assuming that the pivot point is the green dot thats used as a centre to rotate or move an object. thats the dot I'm having problems with.

Here's my file if it helps: [image]

Comment: Perhaps you mean "origin" not "pivot point"? If so, edit mode is designed to change the position of a certain number of vertices/edges/faces, but not all, so the origin does not move in edit mode. To move an object along with a origin, you need to turn on the object mode. You can also set the placement of the origin in the "options" menu or from the drop-down menu "set origin -> ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't edit an object and origin at the same time. To control the origin position you need to:

1. Select the object and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*
2. Select a vertex, edge, or face
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor To Selected*
4. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> back into *Object Mode*
5. <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Set Origin > Origin To 3D Cursor*

[image]